# Oauth return to same page after success/failure, How?

Tags: grails, oauth, oauth-2.0, grails-plugin

I have this in my config

```
callback = "http://xxx/oauth/facebook/callback"
successUri = "http://xxx/oauthCallBack/facebookSuccess"
failureUri = "http://xxx/oauthCallBack/facebookFailure"
```

and its working fine.

now the problem is, I have a sing in link in header which is shared amongst all pages, and when user click on it and authenticates using oauth, I want user to come back on same page from where he/she went for authentication.

How can this be done?
Any help much appreciated.
 
Thanks.

Comment: Save the referrer in a session variable, the redirect there after login.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

solved it myself.

Tried using referrer, but had some issues with it.

So
added hidden field with id=currentURL to form, and onLoad of body, populated this hidden field using javascript, eg:

function initParams() {
        document.getElementById('currentURL').value = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname;
}

and now I have currentURL in params in controller.

Comment: What was the problem you had with referer? The way I see it- if you have to enter the password- then referer doesn't bring you to the right page. But if you're already logged in to the OAuth provider, then referer works fine.
Also, not sure about the form solution you mentioned. Could you elaborate please?